# Moq - Function setup to throw async doesnt count as function call

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I'm writing an unhappy flow unit test.

In my code I setup a function to throw async and later I validate that the function was called once.
This scenario fails and succeeds irregularly, as sometimes it shows no calls were made and sometimes the function is called once (as planned).

Do you know why?

Let me know if any more code is needed.
Thanks!

The test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task ContainerScan_ControllerTest_ErrorFlow()
{
    //Given
    TestsRegistrar.ContainerClient.Reset();
    TestsRegistrar.ContainerClient.Setup(x => x.MyAsyncFunc(It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<List<ContainerScanRecord>>())).ThrowsAsync(new Exception("bad stuff happened"));
    var controller = new ContainersRiskGeneratorController(TestsRegistrar.ContainersGenerator, new Mock<IExtendedLogger>().Object, new Mock<IExtendedLoggerEnricher>().Object);
    var scanId = Guid.NewGuid();
    
    //When
    var result = await controller.SomeUpperFuncthatCallsMyAsyncFunc(scanId, new RiskGenerator.Dto.V3.ContainersScanRequest
    {
        ContainerRecords = new List<RiskGenerator.Dto.V3.SomeDto>
        {
            new RiskGenerator.Dto.V3.SomeDto{
                params here
            }
        }
    });
    
    //Then
    result.Should().BeEmpty();
    TestsRegistrar.ContainerClient.Verify(x => x.MyAsyncFunc(It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<List<ContainerScanRecord>>()), Times.Once, "Container Engine should be called once");
}
```

---

**UDPATE #1**: added the calling funcs

The code for `SomeUpperFuncthatCallsMyAsyncFunc`:

```
[HttpPost("someUrl/{scanId:Guid?}")]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<SomeDto>> SomeUpperFuncthatCallsMyAsyncFunc(Guid? _, [FromBody] ContainersScanRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        Ensure.NotNull(nameof(request), request);
        _extendedLoggerEnricher.Enrich(new { request.ScanId });

        _logger.Info("GenerateContainerRiskAsync called", new { request.ScanId });
        var response =
            await _riskGenerator.TheCallingFuncToMyAsyncFunc(
            request.ScanId,
            request.ContainerRecords
                .Where(x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.DockerFilePath))
                .Select(ContainerScanRiskRecordDto.ToContainerScanRecord).ToList())
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        return response.Select(VulnerableContainerScanRecordDto.ToContainerScanVulnerablerRecord).ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        _logger.Error("Exception thrown during generate GenerateContainerRiskAsync", exception, new { request.ScanId });
        StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        return new List<SomeDto>();
    }
}
```

And the func that calls directly to `MyAsyncFunc`:

```
public async Task<List<(ContainerScanRecord record, ImageVulnerabilitiesDto vulnerabilities)>> TheCallingFuncToMyAsyncFunc(Guid id, IReadOnlyCollection<ContainerScanRecord> containerRecords)
{
    try
    {
        return await
             _containerEngineClient.MyAsyncFunc(id, containerRecords).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        _logger.Error($"[{id}] Could not generate GenerateContainerRiskDataAsync: {exception.Message}", exception);
        throw;
    }
}
```

**UDPATE #2**: figured it out!
Well... it turned out to be a nasty race condition with some other class that initialized the data.
That's why it happened randomly.
Sorry for the hustle and thank you all for your time.

Comment: In the code under test the call to MyAsyncFunc is awaited?

Comment: sure. all the way down.

Comment: Is the exception is handled inside the `SomeUpperFuncthatCallsMyAsyncFunc` ?

Comment: *This scenario fails and succeeds irregularly,* < This means you have potentially a race condition. Could you please share the code of `SomeUpperFuncthatCallsMyAsyncFunc` to see what things can cause the race condition?

Comment: PeterCsala for your question - yes, the exception is handeled inside the calling function. ill update the post

Comment: I don't see anything which might indicate this unpredictable behaviour. Could you please define the following variable inside your test: `bool hasInvoked = false;`? Then could you please add the following method call after the `Setup` but before the `ThrowsAsync` call: `.Callback(() => hasInvoked = true)`? And finally could please replace the `Verify` call with the following: `Assert.True(hasInvoked);`? Does it have the same unpredictable outcome?

Answer (score 0):

As I found out recently, when function throws, its invocation can not be counted. So this is why you may experience such problems.

What you could do is to verify that logger logs an error (the same way you assert that your method was called).

Comment: OP has stated *This scenario fails and succeeds irregularly,* << If the invocation can not be counted then I would expect that the test would always fail.

Comment: @PeterCsala Correct, but I stated this may be the reason and explained how I got around this.